# Drawing edge weights don't work properly in networkx Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

My edge and weight data is like this:
{(0, 1): 7, (0, 2): 3, (1, 4): 6, (1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 2, (2, 3): 2, (3, 4): 4}

But i got an image like this. Which is showing wrong edge weights. What am i missing?

[image]

Here 0->1 has a weight of 7 but it shows 2. What is happening?

I have tried the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
class DRAW:
    def __init__(self):
        self.G=nx.Graph()

    def draw(self,node,track):
        # node data is a list containing nodes like [0,1,2,3,4]
        # track is edge and weight dict like {(0, 1): 7, (0, 2): 3, (1, 4): 6}
        [self.G.add_node(k) for k in node]
        [self.G.add_edge(m[0],m[1],weight=m[2]) for m in track]
        # label list data for the weight show
        label={(k[0],k[1]):k[2] for k in track}
        nx.draw_networkx(self.G,pos=nx.spring_layout(self.G))

        nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(self.G, pos=nx.spring_layout(self.G),edge_labels=label,font_size=25)
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your code this way:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

track =  {(0, 1): 7,
      (0, 2): 3,
      (1, 4): 6,
      (1, 2): 1,
      (1, 3): 2,
      (2, 3): 2,
      (3, 4): 4}


class Draw:
    def __init__(self):
        self.G=nx.Graph()

    def draw(self,node,track):
        # node data is a list containing nodes like [0,1,2,3,4]
        # track is edge and weight dict like {(0, 1): 7, (0, 2): 3, (1, 4): 6}
        [self.G.add_node(k) for k in node]
        [self.G.add_edge(k[0],k[1],weight=v) for k,v in track.items()]
        # label list data for the weight show
        labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(self.G,'weight')
        options = {'font_size':20,
                   'node_color':'red',
                   'label_pos':0.5,#(0=head, 0.5=center, 1=tail)
                   'node_size':1200,
                   'style':'solid',#(solid|dashed|dotted,dashdot)
                   'width':2}
        pos = nx.spring_layout(self.G)
        nx.draw(self.G,
                pos,
                with_labels=True,
                **options)

        nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(self.G,
                                     pos,
                                    edge_labels=labels,
                                    **options)
        plt.savefig("graph.png")
        plt.show()


d = Draw()  
d.draw([*range(5)],track)
```

and you get:

[image]